# CSS List Sprite Alignment

Tags: css, list, navigation, alignment, sprite

I can not for the life of me figure this out.  I have made a list and am using it to create a image based sprite navigator.  I have all the hovering effects done and it displays but no matter what I try I can't get it to align into the center of the page.
HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id = 'logo'></div>




    <ul id="navbar">
        <li id="nav-bio"><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
        <li id="nav-music"><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li id="nav-video"><a href="#">Video</a></li>
        <li id="nav-press"><a href="#">Press</a></li>
        <li id="nav-shows"><a href="#">Shows</a></li>
        <li id="nav-shop"><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    </ul>


    <div class = 'wrapper'>

    <div id = 'blog'>

    </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
 #logo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 190px;
    background:url('Loons-Title.png');
     background-position:center top ;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }

div.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5000px;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    }

#navbar {
    height: 65px;
    width: 700px;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar li {
    float: left;
}
#navbar a {
    display: block;

    padding-top: 66px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-bio { width: 79px;
    background-image: url(Loons-menu-sprite.png);
}
#nav-bio:hover {
    width: 79px;
    background-position: 0px -66px;
}
#nav-music { width: 137px;
    background-image: url(Loons-menu-sprite.png);
    background-position: -79px 0px;}
#nav-music:hover {
    width: 137px;
    background-position: -79px -66px;
}
#nav-video {
    width: 121px;
    background-image: url(Loons-menu-sprite.png);
    background-position: -216px 0px;
 }
#nav-video:hover {
    width: 121px;
    background-position: -216px -66px;
}
#nav-press {
    width: 140px;
    background-image: url(Loons-menu-sprite.png);
    background-position: -337px 0px;
 }
 #nav-press:hover {
    width: 140px;
    background-position: -337px -66px;
}
#nav-shows {
    width: 129px;
    background-image: url(Loons-menu-sprite.png);
    background-position: -477px 0px;
}
#nav-shows:hover {
    width: 129px;
    background-position: -477px -66px;
}
#nav-shop {
    width: 94px;
    background-image: url(Loons-menu-sprite.png);
    background-position: -606px 0px;
 }
 #nav-shop:hover {
    width: 94px;
    background-position: -606px -66px;
}
```

Comment: It's usually better to put the styling, including the image on the A-tag, not the LI. See: preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had it first set up the way you said but late at night I was frustrated and changed it around to see if it would change anything.  Now that its centered i'm going to put it back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#navbar {
    height: 65px;
    width: 700px;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0 auto; /* change */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```